# Photos not appearing under Media->Photos in file upload dialog box (Chrome)

Tags: photos, data-transfer, wordpress

Ok i have a new Mac. New Mac user here. I have a samsung phone and have imported photos from my phone onto my Mac (I assume they are in the filesystem now). When i open "Photos" application i can see all my imported phone pics there.

Now i am using Chrome and I'm attempting to upload photos from my Mac into my wordpress blog. Same situation with facebook or any other website. When the finder dialog box opens and i go to Media->Photos there are no photos showing.

Is this some kind of permissions issue where the dialog that opens cannot access the photos in the photos application? Are the photos presented through the photos application actual files on the drive in the regular filesystem? I am not hooked up to iCloud.

Comment: I'm also unable to drag any photos from the photos application into the drop area of the wordpress website 'upload media' dialog.

Answer (score 2):

The photos in the Photos app are stored in a library. You can drag them out on to the desktop, then open them in Chrome.

Comment: no you can't. that's the issue i presented above. It appears to be some kind of permissions issue with chrome having access to the photos through the file upload dialog. When using Safari the photos appear in the finder/dialog. It would be nice to know how to give chrome permission to access the pictures.

Comment: @billyjean where are you dragging them? Chrome should be able to get any file you have permissions to access.

Comment: why do i need to drag them out into the desktop? When in Safari (some of) those same images are accessible from the photos "folder" in the finder dialog. I'm assuming these photos are actually on my disk correct? So why would i want duplicate copies of them dragged to another location on the disk? Seems like a really poor implementation. I'd really love to be able to have a folder where my photos are that acts like any other folder.  my photos that appear in the photos application do not appear in the upload file selection OS dialog launched through Chrome and some in Safari.

Comment: It's obviously some kind of permissions issue on the files. But it seems to be randomly set by the OS which photos i've imported onto my Mac have what permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, Googled, and found your question here.

After I finally figured it out, I had to come back and share the solution with you:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204669

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 1):

There is one more thing you can try. In Mojave Apple made security and permissions tighter. Try going to "Apple Icon" -> "System Preferences" -> "Security and Privacy" -> "Photos" and check the icon next to "Google Chrome". That should give permissions for using Photos to Chrome.

It is unfortunate that Chrome neither issues a warning nor asks for those permissions.

Comment: what does one do if Google Chrome doesn't appear in the System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Privacy->Photos? There's no little + sign with which to add Chrome, and I can't find where I would get Chrome to request access.

Comment: No idea then, I was pretty sure it appears there the first time, you try to upload photos with chrome.